# Parametricize type by Enum value in Java?

Tags: java, generics, generic-programming, type-safety

I was looking into parametrizing generic classes in Java with Enum values to increase type safety and for some compile-time checks (I know generic parameters are ereased at runtime).

## Premises

With an Enum (from an external dependency I cannot change) of the form

```java
enum VehicleType {
  CAR(1),
  MOTORCYCLE(2),
  BIKE(3);

  int id;

  VehicleType(int n) {
    id = n;
  }
}
```

## Goal

I'd like to express something along the lines of:

```java
/*                 vvvvvvvvv--------------- this is pseudocode here */
class Inventory<VT member of VehicleType> {
  private int amount;
  Inventory<VT>(int n){
    if (n < 0) throw new Exception();
    amount = n;
  }
  int getAmount() { return amount; }

  // This is the crucial part where we would gain something
  // from compile time type checking
  Inventory<VT> add(Inventory<VT> items) {
    return new Inventory<VT>(this.getAmount() + items.getAmount());
  }
}
```

Now, obviously while the definition of the Enum compiles, the second code block which my question is about cannot (that's why I ask).

The type safety thing would come from implicitly matching the "units" or the "types" of the inventory items (in this example) at the type level, catching mismatches at compile time.

Conventionally, if I defined a field `private VehicleType vt;` and set it at the constructor explicitly, I'd have to check for matching types in the method `add(...)` and throw an Exception which needs to be handled elsewhere.

## Questions

### Main question

Can I get this kind of envisioned type safety in Java 8 somehow? Is there an idiom for that (ideally without excessive boilerplate)?

### Bonus question

Is it possible in Java 11?

Comment: Where's the need for generics? If your `Inventory` only supports `VehicleType`, then just remove all the generics information and just use `VehicleType` in place of `VT`. Any `VehicleType` is already a "member of" `VehicleType`, you just need to make sure `null` isn't allowed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to say, you can't use `Inventory<VehicleType.CAR>`.

Comment: Note that enum members are not **types**; they are instances (objects) of the enum type. Because they are not types, you cannot use them as an argument for a type parameter. So, it's not possible in Java 8 and not in Java 11, because it's based on a misunderstanding.